# Fade other elements when one is focussed

Tags: jquery, focus

I have a list of items that I would like to fade when one of them has keyboard focus. The one with keyboard focus should not be faded.

I've done a similar thing with hover and achieved it like so:

```
// Recede other locations when one is hovered.

$('li').hover( 
  function () {
    $('li:not(:hover)').addClass('recede');
  },
  function () {
    $('li').removeClass('recede');
  }
);
```

However, my best attempt at something similar with `.focus()` isn't working...

```
// Recede other locations when one is focussed.
$('li').focus( function () {
  if (!$('li').is(":focus")) {
    $location_item_no_touch.addClass('recede');  
  }
});

$('li').blur( function () {
  $('li').removeClass('recede');
});
```

I've tried a few different approaches, but it seems to be difficult to get the item with `:focus` to not add the `.recede` class. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Add a fiddle. Would make easy for us to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Recede other locations when one is focussed.
$('li').focus( function () {
    $('li').removeClass('recede');
    $(this).addClass('recede');  
});

$('li').blur( function () {
  $('li').removeClass('recede');
});
```

I suppose your `.recede` is applying the fade you need.

Comment: I just arrived at this solution with a colleague - I needed to use $(this) to target the element from the others. Thanks.

Comment: To be more precise, we did this:

`$(li).not($(this)).addClass('recede');`

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
.bind('keydown', function() { isClick = false; })
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vsEg7/14/)

Comment: I have faded-out the selected input type but you can do whatever you want in handler with that input type..Hope this solves your error ..